# Change time format for "Time elapsed:" in Maven Build Logs

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a long running test suite and once run is completed, maven build logs are available in console. The issue is it is not in proper decimal format. Is there anyway to make it decimal.

Current log: `Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3,289.634 s - in TestSuite`

Due to comma in time elapsed `3,289.634 s` facing issue. This is effecting in parsing xml `cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '3,289.634' is not a valid value for 'decimal'.`

Appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

Desire to change the time format.

Comment: Does your native language use commas in this location?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to fix this other that surefire code change and re-build.

The string is formed using [this logic](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/61f03c6903ee19afd7d1e5f37c047dc77b3cf49f/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/ReporterUtils.java#L40).

```java
static String formatElapsedTime( double runTime )
{
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance( Locale.ENGLISH );
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed( true );
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits( 0 );
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits( 3 );
    return numberFormat.format( runTime / MS_PER_SEC );
}
```

So no environmental settings would change this behavior. You can change `true` to false and rebuild your surefire classes to get what you need.